# How do I display the password field on the WordPress user registration screen?

Tags: password

On the registration screen I need to show the password field how do I do this with code without using plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no password field (unless you use a specific plugin). You register for an account with a login name and email.

You then get an email with a link to set your password.

If you want to have users enter a password when they register, you should look into using a plugin or so, like [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/).